# Series - Product of Exponential Function with Confluent Hypergeomtric Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, hypergeometric-function, cauchy-product

Lets say I want to find the series representation for $f(x)$ which is defined as the product of an exponential function with a confluent hypergeometric function,

\begin{equation}
f(x) = e^{-x}\, {_{1}}F_{1}(-a,-b,x)
\end{equation}

where, $a > 0$, and $b> 0$.

Since both terms of the products have power series repsentations, I could simply take the Cauchy product such that,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}x^{n}\right)\,
\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-a)_{n}}{(-b)_{n}\,n!}x^{n}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}\frac{(-a)_{n-k}}{(-b)_{n-k}(n-k)!}\right) \, x^{n}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

However, when the first arguement of the confluent hypergeometric function is a negative integer, the series is truncated to $a+1$ terms, i.e.

\begin{equation}
{_{1}}F_{1}(-a,-b,x) = \sum_{n=0}^{a}\frac{(-a)_{n}}{(-b)_{n}\,n!}x^{n} \quad \text{when} \ a \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}
\end{equation}

Gven the situation at hand (i.e. $-a\in\mathbb{Z}^{-}$) is the product above still valid? Can I just treat the hypergeometric function as infinite series knowing that all terms for $n=a \to\infty$ are zero?

Maybe a better way of framing this question is this: Is there a general solution for this product without prior knowledge of what value $-a$ is?